# WhatsApp API / Library / service for private smart home project

Tags: library, java, api, whatsapp

I am looking for a way to receive WhatsApp messages on an Arduino or Raspberry Pi which also should allow me to detect the sender's number and message.
Several companies in Germany advertise with a WhatsApp Newsletter service people can log in to.

How do they do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a python WhatsApp library called [yowsup](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup) that should let your RaspberryPi act as a client for a WhatsApp account. *See [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/WhatsApp-on-Raspberry-Pi/) for a comprehensive walk-through of doing so.*

This library will definitely allow you to receive messages, with originator details, on your device.